# Convert Question to Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

How do I request that a thread like this [From .NET developer to SharePoint developer - Can it happen?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22435/from-net-developer-to-sharepoint-developer-can-it-happen) be turned into a community wiki thread?  Its not really a question that can be answered by one person?

Answer (score 1):

You can flag the question for moderator attention and include a message requesting the question be converted. I went ahead and converted it.

Comment: Got it.  Looked at the flag options, and none of them seemed to fit.

Comment: Right, you'd have to use the "Other" category.